# Iterator toIndexedSequence length does not match length of interator

Tags: scala, vector, iterator

I'm encountering a weird error when calling toIndexedSequence on an Iterator. The length of the iterator is 81 but the length of the resulting indexedSequence is 257. When I print the indexedSequence I get two vectors. The first one is the correct length of 81 but the second one it prints is 257. I'm not sure why it prints two vectors. The second one seems to be adding zeros between my elements.

```
def apply(source: scala.io.Source): Sudoku = {
    val vec = for( x <- source.toVector if !isWhiteSpace(x) ) yield { if( x>='1' && x<='9') x - 48 else 0 }
    println( vec )
    new Sudoku(vec)
  }
  def isWhiteSpace( char: Char ):Boolean = char == (' ' | '\n')


ouput:
Vector(9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6)
Vector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context as in like code where you compute `seq` variable?

Comment: I have no idea why I'm getting two vectors. It happens with any data structure I use when I try printing it.

Comment: `' ' | '\n'` is not what you think it is. It's the bit-wise OR of 2 chars. See what happens when you do this: `'*' == (' ' | '\n')`

Comment: Wouldn't this do what you want: `source.filterNot(_.isWhitespace).map(c => if (c.isDigit) c.asDigit else 0).toVector`?